# Nested dictionaries to single dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

## I am editing it

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
x= {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
y= {'Accept': 'application/json'}
```

And I need to create final dictionary `z = {x, y}`

### How would I do it?

I have headers variable which accepts the following value

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

Can someone help me to convert following into above format?

```
headers = {
    {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    {'Accept': 'application/json'}
}
```

Currently, this one gives me the following error.

> ```
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
> ```

thanks for help!

Comment: Delete the extra braces? It's extremely unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: how are you getting the initial format? `{}` denotes a dictionary with a key, value pair. Your second `headers` looks like it should be a dictionary

Comment: That second object is not valid JSON / dictionary. What is creating the second object?

Comment: The closest thing i can think of is this `headers = {'name1': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 'name2':{'Accept': 'application/json'}}`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the new headers to be a `list` of two dictionaries, currently that format doesn't make sense seeing as you are making a new `dictionary` that has no `key`s /  `values` instead contains two `dictionaries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. This is how I solved it.

```
z = dict(list(x.items()) + list(y.items()))
```

which resulted as expected

```
   {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can't be hashed in Python -- neither can lists.  I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you want to convert the second headers variable into the first, you need to remove the nested curly brackets.  The second variable doesn't make sense to Python because you have two dictionaries wrapped by dictionary brackets.  If what you want is a list in that second variable, the outer nested brackets need to be list brackets, i.e [ ].

Answer (score 0):

Being as this is not a valid format:

```
headers = {
    {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    {'Accept': 'application/json'}
}
```

I want to assume your goal was to create this:

```
headers = [
    {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    {'Accept': 'application/json'}
]
```

Which can be done like so:

```
headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

new_headers = []

for k in headers:
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict[k] = headers[k]
    new_headers.append(new_dict)

print(new_headers)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 convert.py
> [{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, {'Accept': 'application/json'}]
> ```

Comment: Yeah that happens , and your question is still providing same issue, you are stating turn two dicts into `z = {x, y}` I believe you want to phrase this as `z = [x, y]` , think you are using a dictionary format to store two dictionaries but every element in that dicitonary must have a key and a value so you could have `z = { 'x': 'y'}` but that would mean that you want `x` to be the `key` and `y` to be the `value` or as I stated , it appears you want to place two dictionaries into a list that would be `z = [x, y]`

Comment: It's more like passing 2 headers at the same time like  headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

Comment: it can be one or the other would you like `z = [x, y]` or `z = {x:y}`

Comment: no. it either says  [{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, {'Accept': 'application/json'}]
or     headers = {self.header_content_type_x_www_form_urlencoded: self.header_accept_json}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: sorry it is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish, again your desired result is not a valid format within python

Comment: would you like this output ? `headers = {'application/x-www-form-urlencoded': 'application/json'}` ?

Comment: thank you for the conversations. Which helped me to debug it little deeply.

Comment: @ManojKengudelu if the question is resolved please accept so others users as the nature of this question can be misleading , your welcome :)